# How Can I Configure the SameSite Cookie Attribute in Apache Shiro?

Tags: shiro, apache-commons-beanutils, samesite

I'm developing an EJB-based webservice using Apache Shiro for user access management. I added the [freshly released](https://shiro.apache.org/news.html#1.5.0-released) version 1.5.0 of Apache Shiro to my Maven project to make use of the new `sameSite` cookie attribute. Then I added the configuration of the `sameSite` attribute to my `shiro.ini` file:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
# configure properties (like session timeout) here if desired
sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = true
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.path = /
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.httpOnly = true
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.secure = ${MY_WILDFLY_SHIRO_COOKIE_SECURE}
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.name = mycookie
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.domain = ${MY_WILDFLY_SHIRO_COOKIE_DOMAIN}
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.sameSite = NONE
```

However, if I try to compile this (using Maven), I'm getting the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.1.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project api: Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"api.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to set property 'sessionIdCookie.sameSite' with value [NONE] on object of type org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager.  If 'NONE' is a reference to another (previously defined) object, prefix it with '$' to indicate that the referenced object should be used as the actual value.  For example, $NONE
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to set property 'sessionIdCookie.sameSite' with value [NONE] on object of type org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager.  If 'NONE' is a reference to another (previously defined) object, prefix it with '$' to indicate that the referenced object should be used as the actual value.  For example, $NONE
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to set property 'sessionIdCookie.sameSite' with value [NONE] on object of type org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager.  If 'NONE' is a reference to another (previously defined) object, prefix it with '$' to indicate that the referenced object should be used as the actual value.  For example, $NONE
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Default conversion to org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.Cookie$SameSiteOptions failed.
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: Can't convert value '' to type class org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.Cookie$SameSiteOptions"}}}}
```

What I have tried:

- Manually importing the [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.4) of Apache BeanUtils in the POM file
- Writing `NONE` in single quotes and double quotes
- Using the fully-qualified name
  `org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.Cookie.SameSiteOptions.NONE` instead of
  just `NONE`

How can I configure the `shiro.ini` file so that Shiro's session cookie has the `sameSite` attribute set to `NONE`?

Comment: To anyone who's facing the same issue: If found a workaround for Shiro 1.4.2 - you can (mis)use the comment attribute to sneak in another attribute, like this in the shiro.ini:
`sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.comment = ;SameSite=NONE`
(The semicolon is the delimiter that ends the value of the comment attribute.)

Comment: Did you found a solution for that? Is there any other configuration needed in Wildfly? Where are you getting the: ${MY_WILDFLY_SHIRO_COOKIE_SECURE} ?

Comment: @vished2000 The workaround for Shiro 1.4.2 from my comment did the job for us. Later we got rid of CORS in our application, so we no longer need to set a custom SameSite value. Shiro is at version 1.7.1 now, so I assume this issue would be fully fixed by now (but I cannot tell for sure). The ${...} are Docker environment variables, which get substitutes by the Docker Builder once I build a container in which the WildFly AS runs. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error and I have a fix for it.

The Jira is here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-739

regards,

Comment: Is this fix available in any binary distribution?